# Mutator for unique user attribute

Tags: laravel

In my code the line `User::where('socialite_id', $socialite_id)->exists();` is used so many times, that i want to just write a mutator or sth around it to make this line shorter.

So i need to make mutator, that checks if there's a user with the same `socialite_id` that a new user is about to have.

I've come with

```html
    public function hasUniqueSocialiteIdAttribute($value){
        return !$this->where('socialite_id', $value)->exists();
    }
```

Mabye it is better to catch the duplicate exception and abort on catch, but.. naah.

But this thing is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scope for reusability purposes:

```php
public function scopeSocialiteId($query,$id) {      
    return $query->where('socialite_id', $id);
}
```

and then

```php
User::socialiteId($socialite_id)->exists();
```

For additional info see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes